# decoder function returns garbage string in C. how to fix?

Tags: c, string

The following is a simplified decoding function I made that is supposed to take a string of a specific size and return the string with ascii values of each character one less than the original character in the same position in the original string.

For example, If I call the function with parameters "BCDEF" and 5, then I should be able to have "ABCDE" returned, however, all I get back is mostly garbage.

```
char* dec(char* s,int sz){
int x=0;
unsigned char p=0;
char ss[sz];
if (s){
    for (x=0;x<sz;x++){
        p=s[x];
        p=p-1;
        ss[x]=p;
    }
    return ss;
}
else{return s;}
```

}

And here's how I'm calling it from outside:

```
char *item="BCDEF",*item2="     ";
item2=dec(item,5); 
printf("item= %s",item2);
```

Printing the result of item2 as a string produces garbage even tho I tried reserving fixed sizes.

Compiling the code also produces "warning: function dec returns address of local variable" yet I didn't prepend the variable to return with an &.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dec(char *s, int sz, char *ret)
{
    if ( s == NULL )
    {
        printf ( "\n entered string have NULL value\n " );
        exit ( 0 );
    }

    while ( *s != NULL )
    {
        *ret = (int)*s - 1 ;
        s++;
        ret++;
    }
    *ret = '\0';
}

int main ( void )
{

char * ret = NULL;
ret = (char * ) malloc (5 * sizeof (char ));
dec ("code" , 5, ret );

printf ( "\n %s\n", ret );

free ( ret );

return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work for me. Also, I attempted to adapt to your code by removing the sz function parameter since you're comparing to zero-byte values. Maybe its something with apache that is messing up the code. I'm not sure.

Comment: I am using http://codepad.org to compile my code ... and it is giving correct output.

Comment: I got it to work by leaving the sz parameter in and changing *s != null to sz > 0 and I added sz-- within the loop. but I'll accept the answer since it helps

Answer (score 3):

`ss` is a Local (array) variable in your `dec` function. When the function ends, the array ceases to exist and when you access that pointer/address later its [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of making a local array placed on stack, `malloc` it:

```
char *ss = malloc(sizeof(char)*(sz+1)); //+1 for NUL char 
//do something
return ss;
```

And use `free` to clear the memory when you do not need it.

Comment: But leave enough space for the NUL character at the end.

Comment: @AboveBoth - thank you for improving upon the answers. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I have to use caution with that because I'm making a special apache module. And if I malloc and then return, how do I re-access the variable again? wouldn't the variable also act as a handle?

Comment: @Mike : You will store it in `item2` - the way you are doing now - do your work and then use `free` to clear the memory and assign `NULL` to `item2`.

Comment: oh yes I just remembered. I'll see how well that works

Comment: Ok, char *x=apr_palloc(r->pool, sizeof(char)*(sz+1)) does seem to work, but now I gotta figure out a way to clean the garbage from x without resorting to a for loop

Comment: @Mike: Just do `free(x); x= NULL;`

Comment: what I mean is make all reserved bytes a zero value

Comment: Use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) - If you are not using the pointer uninitialized later for me it should not be a problem.